# How to tweak ie9 to browse faster

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, firefox

Is there any tweak to make Internet Explorer 9 faster for browsing.

Everytime i open ie, it loads slow even on the google home page. But when the same google home page is viewed in Chrome/Firefox it loads faster than IE.

But some of the pages crash in Chrome, and most of the pages are viewed without crashing in ie.

I want to use ie9 but it is always slow. If there are any tweaks to make ie9 faster, please advice

Thanks,

Comment: Pages rarely crash in chrome. Maybe your computer is old?

Comment: No, My computer is not old one.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you [turn off all addon](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-to-manage-add-ons-in-Internet-Explorer-9) and try again. if it's faster, then you can try to turn on the ones you really need.